How can i allocate troops so as to maximize the number of bases conquered without going over a maximum time?
I have a set of bases which are connected by directed edges illustrating which bases can be attacked from any particular base. Bases have a health pool (ex: 1,000,000 hp), and each base has a certain health regeneration rate (ex: 1,500 hp / sec). I have a pool of troops, each member of which can do a certain amount of damage per second. Given a starting node, how can I find the allocation of troops such that the maximum number of surrounding bases are conquered. The second part to this would be how can i maximize this same property while remaining under some certain maxTime
To make it simpler to start, assume we only want to invade up to Depth=1 from the starting node. So only 1 base deep.
An approach ive considered is to essentially iterate over the possible allocations of troops. Say I have two bases that i can conquer from a starting node. If allocations are in increments of say 10% of troops, then i would iterate over 10 variations of the graph where each edge weight is a function of the planet health, regen, and that iteration's allocation of troops (ex: Allocation1 = {base1: 10%, base2: 90%). However this seems super inefficient doesn't scale well when bases have a large number of outgoing edges.
My struggle with this problem is that it seems computationally very complex. Especially since i would like to extend this algorithm to essentially output all the troop allocations along a path between a source node and a target node, but thats a separate problem.

I don't think this is answerable, because this doesn't tell us how the particular allocation of troops is related to which bases are successfully conquered.  What is the condition for a base to be conquered?  Does it suffice that the damage per second exceed the regen by some tiny amount?  If troops finish defeating a base, can they be re-directed towards another base, or is there a requirement that once troops are assigned to a base they must stay there?  Does it take time to move troops along an edge?  Can troops traverse an edge if you haven't conquered the base one one or both endpoints?

Please don't use code blocks to emphasize ordinary textual words.
